# When is transclusion appropriate?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Case in point, I am developing a multi-select control in Angular2, similar in functionality to [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) or a multitude of other controls.

I started by defining what I want the user interface to look like in terms of defining what's included in the dropdown, and came up with two options.

One is to use `@Input()`s for the options:

```
<my-multi-select [options]="options"></my-multi-select>
```

...and then within the template for `my-multi-select`:

```
<div class=option" *ngFor="let option of options">{{option.display}}</div>
```

Ahother is to use transclusion, which is how [material2](https://material.angular.io/components/component/select) appears to do it:

```
<my-multi-select>
  <my-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option"></my-option>
</my-multi-select>
```

...and then within the template for `my-multi-select`:

```
<div class=select-container">
  <ng-content select="my-option"></ng-content>
</div>
```

I was content with the transclusion option, but then when I started to actually implement it rand in to difficulty binding the events coming from `my-option` to `my-multi-select`.  I could try to figure out a way to notify `my-select` of things that are happening in `my-option`, like using an `Observable`, or digging deeper in to using an `@Output` event -- but that feels like trying to jam a square peg in to a round hole when `@Input` variables might just be simpler.

This led me to the question, is transclusion even appropriate here?  And the bigger question, when is transclusion appropriate, and when is using transclusion jamming a square peg in to a round hole?

Answer (score 1):

For your example, it's simple to compare the two aproaches as you are only including one text item as part of the transclusion. This makes using `@Input()` trivial and may well be the best solution.

However, imagine a scenario where you have multiple elements you want to include in your child component, each with custom HTML tags along for the ride. Using trasnclusion this is trivial, but using `@Input()` it requires a few *"hacks"* to get right and isn't very maintainable or extendable.

---

**Explanation**

Building on from this [Todd Motto blog about transclusion](https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content#angular-content-projection) as a reference, we can utilise transclusion to have more complex HTML for our `title` and `content` sections without issue.

*Transculsion Parent*

```
<my-component>
    <my-title>
        <h1>This is the Component title!</h1>
    </my-title>
    <my-content>
        And here's some awesome content.
        <ul>
            <li>First</li>
            <li>Second</li>
        </ul>
    </my-content>
</my-component>
```

*Transclusion Child*

```
<div class="my-component">
    <div>
        Title:
        <ng-content select="my-title"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div>
        Content:
        <ng-content select="my-content"></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now imagine this same scenario using only `@Input()` to declare our elements.

Our binding from the parent isn't very friendly, we definitely don't want to do this for more complex scenarios.

In our child component we have to use `[innerHTML]` to get around interpolation encoding in Angular. Again, this isn't very easy to extend or maintain. This is where in my opinion transclusion really excels.

*Input Parent*

```
<my-component
    [my-title]="<h1>This is the Component title!</h1>"
    [my-content]="And here's some awesome content.<ul><li>First</li><li>Second</li></ul>">
</my-component>
```

*Input Child*

```
 <div class="my-component">
    <div [innerhtml]="'Title:' + my-title"></div>
    <div [innerhtml]="'Content:' + my-content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> This led me to the question, is transclusion even appropriate here?

If want html to look like:

```
<my-multi-select>
  <my-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option"></my-option>
</my-multi-select>
```

Where `my-multi-select` and `my-option` are components, then *transclusion is **the** way to do it*.

Comment: Yep, I get that.  But that was just one option, and in this case I have multiple options available to me.  So put another way, if I can accomplish the same thing either using transclusion or using input variables, what are the key things I should consider when deciding between the two different approaches?

Comment: This is one use case for transclusion, but my no means the only one. In general, transclusion is useful when you want to provide generic HTML for inclusion in the template body.